# Trying to handle a checkbox value as a boolean for input into a database

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Trying to handle the input from a check box as a boolean so that I can input the value amongst others into a database. The value is "mailingList" and i thought i had cracked it but it now just returns a pre defined error in my "catch" which should be unrelated. Below is the $_Post from the form

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
     $email = trim($_POST['email']);
     $password = trim($_POST['pwd']);
     $retyped = trim($_POST['conf_pwd']);
     $firstname = trim($_POST['fname']);
     $lastname = trim($_POST['lname']);
     $company = trim($_POST['company']);
     $mailinglist = trim($_POST['mailingListCheckbox']);
     require_once('./includes/register_user_pdo.inc.php');
  }
?>
```

then there is the related register_user_pdo.inc.php

```
<?php
  require_once('./classes/CheckPassword.php');
  $errors = array();
  if (preg_match('/\s/', $email)) {
     $errors[] = 'Email should not contain spaces.';
  }
  if (!isset($mailingList)) {
    $mailingListValue = FALSE;
}
else {
    $mailingListValue = TRUE;
}
  $checkPwd = new Ps2_CheckPassword($password, 10);
  $checkPwd->requireMixedCase();
  $checkPwd->requireNumbers(2);
  $checkPwd->requireSymbols();
  $passwordOK = $checkPwd->check();
  if (!$passwordOK) {
     $errors = array_merge($errors, $checkPwd->getErrors());
  }
  if ($password != $retyped) {
     $errors[] = "Your passwords don't match.";
  }
  if (!$errors) {
     // include the connection file
     require_once('./includes/connection.inc.php');
     $conn = dbConnect();
     // create a salt using the current timestamp
     $salt = time();
     // encrypt the password and salt with SHA1
     $pwd = sha1($password . $salt);
     // prepare SQL statement
     $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (email, salt, pwd, lastName, firstName, company, mailingList)
     VALUES (:email, :salt, :pwd, :lastName, :firstName, :company, :mailingList)';
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
     // bind parameters and insert the details into the database
     $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':salt', $salt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':lastName', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':firstName', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':company', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':mailingList', $mailingListValue, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
     try {
         $stmt->execute();
         // check number of rows affected by previous insert
         if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
            $success = "$email has been registered. You may now log in.";
         }
     }catch(PDOException $e){
        if ($e->getCode() == 23000)
            $errors[] = "Email is already in use. Please use another email address.";
        else 
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, there was a problem with the database.';
    }
  }
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your top segment of code you are defining

```
$mailinglist = trim($_POST['mailingListCheckbox']);
```

however in your second segment of code you are referencing

```
$stmt->bindParam(':mailingList', $mailingListValue, PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
```

You need to change your first part to

```
$mailingListValue = ....
```

---

**EDIT**

The above answer is wrong, actually it could be this :-

if (!isset($mailingList)) {

"L" is capitalised

Comment: Thanks for the reply, missed that capital L, but its still coming up with the error though unfortunately. the error started after using that if statement, does it look right otherwise to you in terms of the condition?